# Почему дата автоматически не исправляется

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно в классе организовать метод изменения минут, а именно к времени прибавить количество минут. Но не происходит автоматическое исправление, в этом примере получается 64 минут, вместо того что бы было 4 минуты и прибавило +1 к часу.

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
 <style>
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
<script>
class Time{
  constructor(hour,minute,second){
    this.hour = hour;
    this.minute = minute;
    this.second = second;
  }
  showTime(){
    alert(`${this.hour}:${this.minute}:${this.second}`);
  }

  set Hour(newHour){
    if (newHour < 0 || newHour >= 24) throw new Error("Такого не бывает");
    this.hour = newHour;
  }

  set Minute(newMinute){
    if (newMinute < 0 || newMinute >= 60) throw new Error("Такого не бывает");
    this.minute = newMinute;
  }

  set Second(newSecond){
    if (newHour < 0 || newHour >= 60) throw new Error("Такого не бывает");
    this.second = newSecond;
  }

    set changeMinute(deltaMinute){
    this.minute += deltaMinute;
    let currentDate = new Date(this.hour, this.minute, this.second);
    currentDate.setHours(this.hour);
    currentDate.setMinutes(this.minute);
    //currentDate.setMinutes(currentDate.getMinutes() + deltaMinute);
    currentDate.setSeconds(this.second);
     currentDate.getDate();
  }



}
let newTime = new Time(10,14,25);
newTime.showTime();
newTime.Hour = 16;
newTime.showTime(); 
newTime.changeMinute = 50;
newTime.showTime();
</script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: А в чем проблема-то? Почему код должен делать то, что в нем не написано? `Date` это что?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так и не понял что Вы пытались сделать в changeMinute. Вот что сделал Я и это работет:

```js
class Time{
  constructor(hour,minute,second){
    this.hour = hour;
    this.minute = minute;
    this.second = second;
  }
  showTime(){
    console.log(`${this.hour}:${this.minute}:${this.second}`);
  }

  set Hour(newHour){
    if (newHour < 0 || newHour >= 24) throw new Error("Такого не бывает");
    this.hour = newHour;
  }

  set Minute(newMinute){
    if (newMinute < 0 || newMinute >= 60) throw new Error("Такого не бывает");
    this.minute = newMinute;
  }

  set Second(newSecond){
    if (newHour < 0 || newHour >= 60) throw new Error("Такого не бывает");
    this.second = newSecond;
  }

    set changeMinute(deltaMinute){
      this.minute += deltaMinute;
      while(this.minute >= 60)
      {
        this.minute -= 60;
        this.hour += 1;
        if(this.hour > 23)
        {
          this.hour = 0;
        }
      }
  }

}
let newTime = new Time(10,14,25);
newTime.showTime();
newTime.Hour = 16;
newTime.showTime(); 
newTime.changeMinute = 111150;
newTime.showTime();
```

Comment: Не совсем правильно делать  this.hour += 1. Что если будет прибавлено, например, 145 минут?

Comment: Воу, точняк, про это то не подумал.

Comment: Все исправил, должно работать и с 145.

Comment: Нет. Все еще плохо.

Comment: Почему? Не вижу смысла использовать Date, выглядит к тому же не очень.

Comment: Потому что время выполнения у вас зависит от значения deltaMinute. Если ввести 60000, то будет 1000 итераций. А сложность у этой операции О(1), т.е. от значения  deltaMinute не зависит, там всего пара вычислений.

Comment: Нет, дело тут не в этом, сам разобрался. Если в моем способе ввести 25 то часы будут больше 23, а если в способе ниже все будет работать правильно.

Comment: В принципе для часов можно такую же проверку делать. Но я говорил не об этом. Как насчет `this.hour += (deltaMinute - this.minute) / 60` ? И не нужен цикл.

Comment: @Igor ай, конечно же!

Comment: @Эникейщик Math.round() еще. Ну в принципе да, но тогда с тем же 60000 проблема.

Answer (score 2):

```js
class Time {
  constructor(hour, minute, second) {
    this.hour = hour;
    this.minute = minute;
    this.second = second;
  }
  showTime() {
    console.log(`${this.hour}:${this.minute}:${this.second}`);
  }

  set Hour(newHour) {
    if (newHour < 0 || newHour >= 24) throw new Error("Такого не бывает");
    this.hour = newHour;
  }

  set Minute(newMinute) {
    if (newMinute < 0 || newMinute >= 60) throw new Error("Такого не бывает");
    this.minute = newMinute;
  }

  set Second(newSecond) {
    if (newHour < 0 || newHour >= 60) throw new Error("Такого не бывает");
    this.second = newSecond;
  }

  set changeMinute(deltaMinute) {
    this.minute += deltaMinute;
    let currentDate = new Date();
    currentDate.setHours(this.hour);
    currentDate.setMinutes(this.minute);
    currentDate.setSeconds(this.second);
    this.hour = currentDate.getHours();
    this.minute = currentDate.getMinutes();
    this.second = currentDate.getSeconds();
  }
}

let newTime = new Time(10, 14, 25);
newTime.Hour = 16;
newTime.showTime();
newTime.changeMinute = 50;
newTime.showTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
class Time{
  constructor(hour,minute,second){
    this.hour = hour;
    this.minute = minute;
    this.second = second;
  }
  showTime(){
    console.log(`${this.hour}:${this.minute}:${this.second}`);
  }

  set Hour(newHour){
    if (newHour < 0 || newHour >= 24) throw new Error("Такого не бывает");
    this.hour = newHour;
  }

  set Minute(newMinute){
    if (newMinute < 0 || newMinute >= 60) throw new Error("Такого не бывает");
    this.minute = newMinute;
  }

  set Second(newSecond){
    if (newHour < 0 || newHour >= 60) throw new Error("Такого не бывает");
    this.second = newSecond;
  }

    set changeMinute(deltaMinute)
    {
      this.hour=this.deltaMinute/60;
      this.hour=this.hour%23;
      this.hour= Math.floor( this.hour);
      this.minute=this.deltaMinute%60;
    
    }
}
let newTime = new Time(10,14,25);
newTime.showTime();
newTime.Hour = 16;
newTime.showTime(); 
newTime.changeMinute = 111150;
newTime.showTime();
```